# iOS record a midi file

Tags: ios, midi, recording

I am receiving midi events from an external keyboard, and looking for a way to record them to a midi file. Are there any Obj C libraries available to do this?

Comment: If you already have MIDI events, writing them into a file is trivial. Look at the MIDI file specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to write a file creation routine from scratch, you can use the `MusicPlayer` and `MusicSequence` API method [MusicSequenceFileCreate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicSequence_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/MusicSequenceFileCreate) to generate a .mid file. You'll need to create an instance of a `MusicSequence` and a [MusicTrack](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicTrack_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009332) to add the incoming MIDI events to. The advantages would be the clock is handled and you get preview/playback capability.